# pass id in react.js to make update view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have listing view working correctly and I want to pass data to update view by Id - in URL Id is passed correctly, but without data saved to this Id. In console log id is tagged as undefined

UpdateCar.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CarServices from '../../Services/CarServices';


class UpdateCar extends Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      carId: this.props.match.id,
      brand: '',
      color: ''

    }
    this.changeBrandHandler = this.changeBrandHandler.bind(this);
    this.changeColorHandler = this.changeColorHandler.bind(this);
    this.getCarId = this.getCarId.bind(this);
    this.updateCar = this.updateCar.bind(this);

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    CarServices.getCarById(this.state.carId).then((res) => {
      let car = res.data;
      this.setState({
        brand: car.brand,
        color: car.color

      });
    });
  }

  changeBrandHandler = (event) => {
    this.setState({ brand: event.target.value });
  }



  changeColorHandler = (event) => {
    this.setState({ color: event.target.value });
  }

  updateCar = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let car = { brand: this.state.brand, color: this.state.color };
    console.log('test:   ' + JSON.stringify(car));
    console.log('id => ' + JSON.stringify(car.carId));


  }

  cancel() {
    this.props.history.push('/showCars');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className='container'>
          <div className='row'>
            <div className='card col-md-6 offset-md-3 offset-md-3'>
              <h3 className='text-center'> Edit car </h3>
              <div className='cardBody'>
                <form>
                  <div className='form-group'>
                    <label> Brand: </label>
                    <input placeholder="brand" name="brand" className="form-control"
                      value={this.state.brand} onChange={this.changeBrandHandler} />

                    <label> Color: </label>
                    <input placeholder="color" name="color" className="form-control"
                      value={this.state.color} onChange={this.changeColorHandler} />


                  </div>

                  <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.updateCar}>Save</button>
                  <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.cancel.bind(this)} style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }}>Cancel</button>

                </form>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default UpdateCar;
```

CarServices.js
When I hardcode id in url it works correclty - I don't know why I don't have any data from database in placeholders

```
import axios from 'axios';
const CAR_API_BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/car"

class CarServices{

    getCars(){
        return axios.get(CAR_API_BASE_URI);
    }

    addCar(car){
        return axios.post(CAR_API_BASE_URI, car);
    }

    getCarById(id){
      return axios.get(CAR_API_BASE_URI  + '/' + id);
      //return axios.get("http://localhost:8080/car/2"); - correclty view data from database saved with id:2

    }



}

export default new CarServices();
```

ListCar.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CarServices from '../../Services/CarServices';

class ListCar extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            cars: []
        }
        this.addCar = this.addCar.bind(this);
        this.editCar = this.editCar.bind(this);


    }
    addCar(){
        this.props.history.push('/addCar');
    }

    editCar(id){
        this.props.history.push(`/editCar/${id}`);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        CarServices.getCars().then((res)=>{
            this.setState({ cars: res.data})
        })
    }

    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2 className='text-center'>Car list </h2>
                <div className='row'>
                    <button className='btn btn-primary' onClick={this.addCar} style={{marginLeft: "15px"}} >Add car</button>
                </div>
                <div className='row'></div>
                    <table className='table table-striped table-bordered'>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th className='text-center'>Id</th>
                                <th className='text-center'>brand</th>
                                <th className='text-center'>color</th>
                                <th className='text-center'>action</th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            { 
                                this.state.cars.map(
                                    car =>
                                    <tr key = {car.carId}>
                                        <td className='text-center'>{car.carId}</td>
                                        <td className='text-center'>{car.brand}</td>
                                        <td className='text-center'>{car.color}</td>
                                        <td className='text-center'>
                                            <button onClick ={ () => this.editCar(car.carId)} className="btn btn-info">Update </button>
                                            <button style={{marginLeft: "10px"}}  className="btn btn-danger">Delete </button>
                                            <button style={{marginLeft: "10px"}}  className="btn btn-info">View </button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                )} 
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ListCar;
```

Comment: Since you're getting the ID from the props using `this.props.match.id` I can't help you much without seeing the parent component

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `UpdateCar` component is correctly rendered on a `Route` and receives the route props, the issue is likely that `this.props.match.id` won't necessarily be defined in the `constructor` when the component is mounting.

If you must reference `props` in the `constructor` then reference the passed `props` argument.

```
constructor(props) { // <-- reference this props
  super(props)

  this.state = {
    carId: props.match.id, // reference props arg
    brand: '',
    color: ''
  }
  ...

}
```

It's better to reference props directly though as it's considered anti-pattern in React to store props into local state.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const { match } = this.props;

  if (match.id) {
    CarServices.getCarById(match.id)
      .then((res) => {
        const { brand, color } = res.data;
        this.setState({ brand, color });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // catch and handle any Promise rejections or thrown errors
      });
  }
}
```

Don't forget to also handle the `id` route path parameter changing *while* the `UpdateCar` component is mounted.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  const { match } = this.props;

  if (prevProps.match.id !== match.id) {
    CarServices.getCarById(match.id)
      .then((res) => {
        const { brand, color } = res.data;
        this.setState({ brand, color });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // catch and handle any Promise rejections or thrown errors
      });
  }
}
```